# Converting Form-data to HTTPClient post request

Tags: java, rest

I have this request from POSTMAN

```
    POST /v1/files HTTP/1.1

    Postman-Token: ab620166-b3ce-c21f-0e29-97cd43111daa
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename=""
 Content-Type: 


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image2"; filename=""
Content-Type: 

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I have tried converting it to HTTPClient post as

```
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addBinaryBody("image1",new(File("/image1.jpg"))
                .addBinaryBody("image2",new(File("/image2.jpg"))
                .build();
```

I have also tried using bodyPart instead of addBinarybody...

I still get a bad request from the server, Anything I am missing?